# No primary or single public constructor found for interface MultipartFile

Tags: java, spring-boot, graalvm

```
No primary or single public constructor found for interface org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile - and no default constructor found either
```

I'm trying to do a file upload, this is my controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/blob")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class MyBlobRestController {
    private final MyBlobService myBlobService;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public List<String> blobitemst() {
        return myBlobService.listFiles();
    }


    @GetMapping("/download/{filename}")
    public byte[] download(@PathVariable String filename) {
        log.info("download blobitem: {}", filename);
        return myBlobService.downloadFile(filename).toByteArray();
    }

    @PostMapping("/upload")
    @CrossOrigin("*")
    public String uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("teste");
        log.info("Filename :" + file.getOriginalFilename());
        log.info("Size:" + file.getSize());
        log.info("Contenttype:" + file.getContentType());
        myBlobService.storeFile(file.getOriginalFilename(),file.getInputStream(), file.getSize());
        return file.getOriginalFilename() + " Has been saved as a blob-item!!!";
    }
}
```

I'm using graalVM to compile the code to binaries and Spring Native.

Here is the request I'm trying after adding `@RequestParam("file")`

curl -F file=@/home/mikhael/teste.txt http://localhost:8080/api/blob/upload

This request is resulting in 400 Bad Request Error

Comment: You need to tell Spring how to create the file, probably by using `@RequestParam`.

Comment: I tried it, but aways I did the request I received 400 Bad Request. I will update the question with it and the request I'm doing

Comment: Don't know *curl* that much, but don't you have to provide the request method? `-X POST` or something. I thought the default would always be `GET`

Comment: can you provide a minimal reproducer ?